# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setup'; django setup working in one project but not other

Tags: python, django, django-settings

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import os, sys, subprocess, time, re, ast

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "webapi.server.project.settings")

import django
django.setup()

from django.apps import apps
```

try:

```
cchilders: ./write_creation_tests.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./write_creation_tests.py", line 17, in <module>
    django.setup()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setup
```

if I remove the setup attempt I can't import apps:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import os, sys, subprocess, time, re, ast

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "webapi.server.project.settings")

from django.apps import apps
```

try:

```
cchilders: ./write_creation_tests.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./write_creation_tests.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django.apps import apps
ImportError: No module named apps
```

in manage.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "webapi.server.project.settings")
```

thus my `os.environ` setting matches the format in another project. I run this script the same way in the other django project and it works, but not in my webapi. These projects are on pythonpath. How can I setup django? Thank you

Comment: The error suggests that you're running Django 1.6 or older, in which case you don't need to call `setup()`.

Comment: The `django.apps` module was added in Django 1.7. You'll need to upgrade Django or change the script to work with your version of Django. Upgrading is recommended, because 1.7 and older are now end of life, and do not receive security fixes.

Comment: without the setup I get ImportError: No module named apps

Comment: yes I have Django==1.6.10

Comment: Both `django.setup()` and `django.apps` were added in 1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade your version of Django to a supported version. Newer versions of Django have the `setup` function. See the [list of supported Django versions](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions)

The answer was in the comments:

> The error suggests that you're running Django 1.6 or older, in which case you don't need to call setup(). – knbk Mar 23 '16 at 16:14

> The django.apps module was added in Django 1.7. You'll need to upgrade Django or change the script to work with your version of Django. Upgrading is recommended, because 1.7 and older are now end of life, and do not receive security fixes. – Alasdair Mar 23 '16 at 16:23

> Both django.setup() and django.apps were added in 1.7.