# Running python functions using IronPython in C#

Tags: c#, ironpython

Im trying to import use a python script in C# by using IronPython but an error keeps coming up which I don't understand, seems like it had problems importing the module. The python file runs fine by itself and i tested a simple script that prints "hello" and it worked so I might just be importing the module wrong somehow.

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll**

**Additional information: 'module' object has no attribute 'setup'**

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di7qY.png)

This is the code im trying to run on my C# program

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ICollection<string> paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
string modulePath = @"D:\Python\Lib";
paths.Add(modulePath);
string modulePath2 = @"D:\Python\Lib\site-packages";
paths.Add(modulePath2);
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
dynamic py = engine.ExecuteFile(@"broadlink.py");
```

This is the code in my python

```
import broadlink

broadlink.setup('*****', '*****', 3)
devices = broadlink.discover(timeout=5)
```

Comment: You have to post error as text (maybe in few years all bots will be able to index text from pictures directly). If you would do it directly into google, then you would find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36183241/1997232).. may not be your case, but you know what to do.

Comment: @Sinatr sorry about that ill change that now. and sadly i am not using django here and sadly I am not making a django project and my module is up do date so simply upgrading isn't an option